# Motivating undergraduates in learning about the Casimir element

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, lie-algebras, advice

Next week I will give a lecture about a chapter in Lie Algebras (I'm myself an undergraduate student).
One of my topics is about the construction of the Casimir element (from Humphreys' book).

I'm wondering, can you share some examples of uses of the Casimir element from your field, that can be understood by math undergraduates (with background in most common fields by now), that I can research further and elaborate on?

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74689/motivating-the-casimir-element), and the references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks, I've seen those. I asked here hoping to get something from a different perspective; "from your field..". Thanks though